# SSO With AngularJS, get user details

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, cookies, single-sign-on

Consider this scenario:

I hit a AngularJS based UI url which is SSO protected in a new browser window, for eg. `https://somedev.domain.com`

This makes a GET request to the above url. Now, the browser prompts me for a username and password for authentication, because of the redirect from `https://somedev.domain.com` to `https://sso.domain.com`

I enter the details, on success of which `https://sso.domain.com` responds by setting a cookie on the browser and sends back user details of the logged in user like Username in a response header and the UI page is loaded.

*Is there a way* in AngularJS to intercept this response and get the details of the logged in user?

PS. I can access the set cookie using $cookie.

Answer (score 1):

This is largely dependent on what technology you use for SSO.  OAuth has a mechanism by which a key is returned to the originating page which can be used to access the authenticating service in order to retrieve the users information.

Based on limited knowledge of your environment, the most universally acceptable solution would to to utilize the `angular-cookies.js` module and access the cookie directly using `$cookies`.  I'm assuming the cookie will not include any user information, as these are often times just session identifiers, but you can then use the cookie session identifier to make a request to the SSO server and request the user information.

Please note, the SSO server will need to generate cookies which are generic to a domain, meaning they do not specify a subdomain.